# Compile with different settings in different commands

Tags: command, sbt, project

I have a project defined as follows:

```
  lazy val tests = Project(
    id   = "tests",
    base = file("tests")
  ) settings(
    commands += testScalalib
  ) settings (
    sharedSettings ++ useShowRawPluginSettings ++ usePluginSettings: _*
  ) settings (
    libraryDependencies <+= (scalaVersion)("org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % _),
    libraryDependencies <+= (scalaVersion)("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _),
    libraryDependencies += "org.tukaani" % "xz" % "1.5",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq()
  )
```

I would like to have three different commands which will compile only some files inside this project. The `testScalalib` command added above for instance is supposed to compile only some specific files.

My best attempt so far is:

```
lazy val testScalalib: Command = Command.command("testScalalib") { state =>
      val extracted = Project extract state
      import extracted._

      val newState = append(Seq(
          (sources in Compile) <<= (sources in Compile).map(_ filter(f => !f.getAbsolutePath.contains("scalalibrary/") && f.name != "Typers.scala"))),
          state)

      runTask(compile in Compile, newState)

      state
  }
```

Unfortunately when I use the command, it still compiles the whole project, not just the specified files...

Do you have any idea how I should do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create different configurations like `compile` and `test`, and have the appropriate settings values that would suit your needs. Read [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) in the official sbt documentation and/or [How to define another compilation scope in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14656592/1305344)

Answer (score 0):

I would not create additional commands, I would create an extra configuration, as @JacekLaskowski suggested, and based on the answer he had cited.

This is how you can do it (using Sbt 0.13.2) and `Build.scala` (you could of course do the same in `build.sbt`, and older Sbt version with different syntax)

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val Api = config("api") 

  val root = Project(id="root", base = file(".")).configs(Api).settings(custom: _*)

  lazy val custom: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Api)(Defaults.configSettings ++ Seq(
    unmanagedSourceDirectories := (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile).value,
    classDirectory := (classDirectory in Compile).value,
    dependencyClasspath := (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value,
    unmanagedSources := {
      unmanagedSources.value.filter(f => !f.getAbsolutePath.contains("scalalibrary/") && f.name != "Typers.scala")
    }
  ))

}
```

now when you call `compile` everything will get compiled, but when you call `api:compile` only the classes matching the filter predicate.

Btw. You may want to also look into the possibility of defining different `unmanagedSourceDirectories` and/or defining [`includeFilter`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/sxr/Keys.scala.html#326312).

Comment: If works no need to thanks, just accept / up vote is enough ;)